# Herarchy between modules in angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module, hierarchy

I want to extend a component from an abstract class which lives in a shared module. But when I try to export that class in shared.module, I receive an error in shared module: 
`Cannot assign abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type`

Is it possible to do that and if the answer is yes how do I get it done?

this is the abstract class:

```
export abstract class BaseComponent extends SimpleComponent {
    protected _clearHubConnection: HubConnection;
    subscription: any;
    protected programService: ProgramService;
    protected toolbarService: ToolbarService;
    private _clearMethod: string;
    protected _config: ConfigService;

    constructor(data: DataService, programService: ProgramService, httpClient: HttpClient,
        toolbarService: ToolbarService, translateService: TranslateService, config: ConfigService, clearMethodValue?: string) {
        super(data, httpClient, translateService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this vice versa:

```
class SimpleComponent extends BaseComponent
```

Your simple component should be non abstract, the BaseComponent is abstract.

Comment: What I want to do is to use something like otherComponent extends BaseComponent this last it’s in another module

Comment: SimpleComponent exits in the same module

Comment: then you have to make the BaseComponent known to the SimpleComponent by importing the module where the BaseComponent is declared into the module where the SimpleComponent is declared. Also, you have to export the BaseComponent in the module where it is declared that it is visible for other modules. But I would honestly question your architecture here - except you created a SharedModule.

Comment: Both simpleComponent and BaseComponent will be in  sharedModule I want to use it in others module